# DataTemplateSelector without code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplateselector

Is it possible to use `DataTemplateSelector` in a XAML-only way, i.e. without code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *define* the actual DataTemplateSelector class in XAML if that's what you are asking.

Once you have defined a DataTemplateSelector class using C# or whatever your preferred programming language is you can use it in your XAML markup though:

```
<Window ... xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TaskListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        ...
```

Please refer to the documentation on MSDN for more information and a full example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep. That's what I'm asking. I thought we might have some concrete selector class within the framework that we could instantiate within xaml without writing one in the code-behind.

Comment: There is only the DataTemplateSelector class but of course this one doesn't contain any of your custom logic to select the correct DataTemplate so it makes no sense to use it. This means that you have to create your own custom class that derives from the built-in DataTemplateSelector. And you cannot do this, i.e. define a class, in XAML.

Comment: I was hoping for a concrete `DataTemplateSelector` wherein I could write template-selection logic within XAML. Much like we use `DataTriggers` and `MultiTriggers` to write logic in XAML.

Comment: Ok, but there is no such class available. You will have to create one yourself. I guess this answers your question.